# Select information from last item and join to the total amount

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

Suppose I have a table like this:

> id | dates | customer | sale

And want to select, for each customer:

- number of purchases
- last purchase value
- total amount of purchases, when it has a positive value

With this table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
    id int auto_increment primary key, 
    dates date,
    customer int,
    sale int
);
```

And this data:

```
INSERT INTO sales
    (dates, customer, sale)
VALUES
    ('2012-01-01', 1, 2),
    ('2012-02-01', 1, 8),
    ('2012-03-01', 2, 1),
    ('2012-04-01', 2, 7),
    ('2012-05-01', 2, -5),
    ('2012-06-01', 1, 5)
```

My results should be:

```
customer | sales | last_sale
1           3        5
2           3        7
```

I cannot figure out how to get it. I have reached this:

```
SELECT s.customer, COUNT(s.sale) total_sales, last_sale FROM sales AS s
JOIN
  (SELECT customer, sale last_sale FROM sales GROUP BY customer ORDER BY dates DESC) AS t
  ON t.customer=s.customer
GROUP BY s.customer
```

But it is not working. Any ideas of how to get this data?

All code is in [SQL fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8561/15)

Comment: can you show your desired result based on the data at fiddle?

Comment: Sure, @JW, I have edited my post to show it properly. It was here but not quite clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT a.customer, count(a.sale), max_sale
FROM sales a
INNER JOIN (SELECT customer, sale max_sale 
            from sales x where dates = (select max(dates) 
                                        from sales y 
                                        where x.customer = y.customer
                                        and y.sale > 0
                                       )

           )b
ON a.customer = b.customer
GROUP BY a.customer, max_sale;
```

[SQL DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8561/44)

Comment: Hi again. Suppose the sales table was enormous (it is). Would it be faster to do this query with a sub-query instead of a join? Also: how can I get the newer and then the previous to the newer? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.customer, 
       COUNT(a.sale) total_sales,
       c.sale
FROM   sales a
       INNER JOIN
        (
          SELECT  a.*
          FROM    sales a
                  INNER JOIN
                  (
                    SELECT  Customer, MAX(Dates) max_date
                    FROM    sales
                    WHERE   sale > 0
                    GROUP   BY Customer
                  ) b ON a.customer = b.customer AND
                          a.dates = b.max_date
        ) c ON a.customer = c.customer
GROUP  BY a.customer, c.sale
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8561/53)

Comment: Both answers are phantastic, thank you very much! I marked the other one as the "good one" because it was the first I tried.